# Sencha Touch Model: Difference between fields and variables

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have two models but not able to find difference between both

1. `Ext.define('Contact', {
           extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
           config: {
               firstName: null,
               lastName: null 
           }
       });`
2. `Ext.define('Contact', {
           extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
           config: {
               fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
           }
       });`

for first one sencha generated set and get method but for second why sencha does not generate set and get methods

Answer (score 2):

The first one defines two properties named `firstName` and `lastName` while the second and correct one defines the fields `firstName` and `lastName`

When using the first one the model will never be able to provide data operations via `get()`/`set()`

Note that a reader requires a field definition to "read" data into the model. You will find the data the reader used to fill the internal  `data` property (used by the getter & setter) in the `rawData` property.